# Поворот объекта к объекту

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть враг и помощник. Проблема: Помощник при использования кода из конца поста, работает неправильно, и поворачивается не так, как нужно.

[image: Правильно]

[image: Не правильно]

С тем кодом, который предложил KOTIK, сначала помощник действительно подходит к врагу, смотря на него, а подходя к нему происходит вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желаемое поведение: чтобы он подходил на достаточное расстояние к врагу, причём смотря на него, и уничтожал его, а не поворачивался и бежал за врагом.

Он поворачивается вокруг врага, а затем переходит на другую сторону. А вот это происходит когда он повернулся и идёт за врагом по другой стороне:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он уже смотрит левее врага. Напомню, когда он шёл к нему в начале, он смотрел чётко на него.

**Фрагменты кода:**

```
transform.LookAt(enemy);
transform.LookAt(enemy, Vector3.left);
```

Тут помощник хоть и повёрнут к врагу, но подходя к нему он переворачивается.

```
var q = Quaternion.LookRotation(nearest.transform.position - transform.position);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, q, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
```

В этом фрагменте всё более-менее хорошо в начале, но в конце он наклоняется не туда.
[image: Наклон]

Весь код из Update:

```
nearest = FindClosestEnemy().gameObject;
    var q = Quaternion.LookRotation(nearest.transform.position - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, q, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, nearest.transform.position);
    Debug.Log(distance);
    if (distance >= 5f) transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nearest.transform.position, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Весь код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class KnifeHelperLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject[] enemy;
    GameObject closest;

    public GameObject nearest;
    public float radian_angle = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private Transform point;

    void Start()
    {
        enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
    }

    GameObject FindClosestEnemy()
    {
        float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject go1 in enemy)
        {
            Vector3 diff = go1.transform.position - position;
            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (curDistance < distance)
            {
                closest = go1;
                distance = curDistance;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }
    public void LookAt(Vector3 point)
    {
        var direction = point - transform.position; // получить направление
        direction.y = 0f; // обнулить y, чтобы не смотреть вверх-вниз
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-direction, Vector3.up); //первый аргумент - направление вперед, второй - направление вверх
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, 10f * Time.deltaTime); // либо вместо Slerp использовать RotateTowards
    }

    void Update()
    {
        nearest = FindClosestEnemy().gameObject;
        LookAt(nearest.transform.position);
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, nearest.transform.position);
        Debug.Log(distance);
        if (distance >= 2.5f) transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nearest.transform.position, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void LookAtEnemy()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обнули ось Y у вектора направления.

```
public class Something : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _point;
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 10f;
        
    public void LookAt(Vector3 point)
    {
        var direction = point - transform.position; // получить направление
        direction.y = 0f; // обнулить y, чтобы не смотреть вверх-вниз
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, Vector3.up); //первый аргумент - направление вперед, второй - направление вверх
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, _speed * Time.deltaTime); // либо вместо Slerp использовать RotateTowards
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        LookAt(_point.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот тут уже лучше, но он странно поворачивается когда подходит к врагу. Я обновил пост, добавил туда скриншотов.

Comment: @Zenith Лучше бы вместо скриншотов код свой добавил

Comment: Ладно, добавил код

Comment: @Zenith у меня все работает. Подходит на расстояние 2.5, стоит и смотрит на врага. У тебя он куда-то в другую сторону смотрит, потому что модель в другую сторону повернута, поэтому ты, похоже, и изменил direction на -direction. Перед - положительное значение оси z

Comment: Да, так и есть. Я изменил direction.z на 180f, изменил -direction на direction, теперь он идёт к врагу лицом, но перестаёт поворачиваться к нему. Когда было -direction, при изменении позиции врага, помощник быстро поворачивался к нему. И да, враги двигаются вперёд. Если враг стоит (с -direction), всё нормально.

Comment: @Zenith [Так](https://ibb.co/HFwMTnW) оно должно работать? Если да, то ищи проблемы у себя, твой и свой код я никак не менял.